Is there a way to show a login screen when app becomes inactive and then once user login, the app resumes like nothing happened in flutter?
The thing I want to implement - App launches from splash screen, goes to login screen and then to home screen and user can continue from there. Now let's assume the user is on profile screen and then minimized the app, login screen should be shown immediately the app is resumed, user login and then continues whatever they were doing which is resuming the profile screen they were on.
My solution so far - I've created a widget that extends widget binding observer and when the app goes inactive, I use pushNamed to show the login route. Now login goes to home and so the app doesn't resume where the user left off.
Problem - I want app to resume wherever the user left off and maintaining whatever routes they've had before the app went inactive.
My other thoughts was using an overlay to show the login and then dismissing upon successful login but it doesn't seem right.

You can delete all the routes in the history and replace the current route with login route:
void clearStackAndNavigate(BuildContext? context, String path) {
  if (context != null) {
    while (GoRouter.of(context).canPop()) {
      GoRouter.of(context).pop();
    }

    GoRouter.of(context).replace(path);
  }
}

You can use Local storage to keep track of current screen before inactivity.

I've edited the question for better clarity. Please check it out

The solution works for what you want to do, you can use that function to navigate to login so they can’t just go back to the previous screen by swiping.

Keep a track of the last active page name with pushNamed from local storage.
Update the login screen logic, if there’s a value in the active page, navigate to that screen and clear the local storage, else navigate to home.


Actually realized i was making it complex, i did not need to clear routes or anything, i just need to push the login in and add popscope so it closes the app if user attempts to go back.  i appreciate the help though
